# How to us VS 2012 to create Web API that connects to SQL Server Database and returns data in a JSON array

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, visual-studio-2012

I am new to Web APIs and am attempting to create one that connects to an existing SQL Server Database, queries the database for information, and then returns that information in the form of a JSON array. I have spent the last few days Googling how to accomplish this and the results so far have not helped much. I've figured out how to setup the Server Explorer to connect to my database and I've setup a Model class. Here's what my Model class looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebAPI.Models
{
    public class EventsModel
    {
        public string eventName { get; set; }
        public string eventDate { get; set; }
        public string eventScanStart { get; set; }
        public string eventScanStop { get; set; }
        public int eventCredits { get; set; }
        public int eventID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How would I go about creating a Controller that interfaces with the Model that I've created and uses the SQL Connection to pull data?

EDIT 1:
Yes, I forgot to mention that I'm attempting to use MVC. Paul, I have implemented your code so my controller now looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebAPI.Models;

namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class EventsController: Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Index()
        {
            var events = new EventsModel();

            // populate the event from the database here

            return Json(events, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

What exactly goes in the spot "// populate the event from the database here"?

Comment: are you familiar with linq to SQL? write a linq query that points to a `DataClassesDataContext` then from there you can return the linq query vai `JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
json = jss.Serialize(yourLinqQueryObject);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention using MVC, but it sounds like you are...

```
namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class EventsController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Index()
        {
            var event = new EventsModel();

            // populate the event from the database here

            return Json(event, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

/Events/Index should return your JSON.